# Удалить из двухуровневого массива массив по значению

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть двухуровневый массив, допустим такой:

```
arr = [
  // ID, param1, param2
  [1,'asd','asd'],
  [2,'dsa','dsa']
];
```

Как удалить массив "второго уровня", по его значению, допустим `arr[i][0];`?

Comment: Попробуйте так `arr[i].splice(0, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (MDN)

```js
let oldArray = [
  // ID, param1, param2
  [1, 'asd', 'asd'],
  [2, 'dsa', 'dsa'],
  [3, 'dsa', 'dsa'],
  [4, 'dsa', 'dsa'],
  [5, 'dsa', 'dsa']
];

let deletingIndex = 3; // индекс, который нужно удалить
let newArray = oldArray.filter(item => deletingIndex !== item[0]);
console.log(newArray);
```